# Is "I'm John Doe, born 2000, currently a construction worker at a small company" correct English?

Tags: prepositions, time

Is "I'm John – John Doe, born 2000, currently a construction worker at a small company" correct English?

I'm specifically wondering about "born 2000" vs. "born in 2000", the latter of which sounds over-correct and unnecessary to me.

Comment: It depends on who is the addressee.   If it's an employer there's nothing "over correct" or formal writing …*born in 2000*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ah, that relieves me. The audience is informal and as long as "born 2000" is not completely always wrong, I'll probably use that.

Comment: Omitting "I was... in" is no more wrong than omitting "I am" from the next phrase. It just makes it a resumé of information rather than a complete sentence.

Comment: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=born+in+2000%2Cborn+2000&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) would strongly suggest that 'born in 2000' is far the more common choice (but G ngrams under-represent conversational registers, I'm sure). What surprised me is that the proportion of people preferring to delete the preposition _in_ is very similar in the UK and the US; I'd have expected the deletion to be far more common in the States, and would almost always include _in_ myself.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing "over correct" about "born in 2000", and that would be the words that I'd use in this kind of fairly informal speech.  But actually I'd probably be more likely to give my age rather than my birthdate:  "I'm John, John Doe, 23 years old, ..."

However "born 2000" is possible, in a sufficiently casual context. It just wouldn't be how I'd want to say.

There is something odd about such "planned informality". Informality normally occurs when the rules are relaxed because the speech isn't planned.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on the age of your audience.

For those of us that grew up in the twentieth century, it was easy to recognise that a number was a year because of the way it was expressed. For example, 1965 as a *number* would be said as "one thousand, nine hundred and sixty five", whereas the *year* would be "nineteen sixty-five". Even historical years that marked a new century, like 1800, were "eighteen hundred" and not "one thousand eight hundred".

The year 2000 was the first year in most people's living memory that is pronounced exactly the same way as the number the numerals represent (ie it isn't "*twenty hundred*"). For a long time before the turn of the millennium, we all spoke about that future date as "*the year two thousand*". For that reason, "*born 2000*" could sound a little odd to persons of a certain age. It certainly sounds jarring to me, and feels you should qualify it by saying "*born in (the year) 2000*" just to make it clear you mean the year, which I admit is ridiculous because it couldn't possibly mean anything else. Pop culture from the twentieth century seems to reflects this too - "*party like it's 1999*" sang Prince, while Pulp sang "*let's all meet up **in the year** 2000*".

To be clear, I'm not saying that the correct way to express this is the way that sounds right to me - I am just highlighting why some might find it jarring while others would not.

Comment: No votes for the equivalent *born during the last year of the twentieth century*, eh? :)